# Compile Error in Solidity unable to compile in remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am getting the following error. Could you please help me in solving by looking into the code.

```
/////ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
function unlockMessage(string name) public payable returns (bool) {
^------^  ///// 
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract TrojanSecret {
// Data Types
uint memberCount;

string public name;
string public symbol;

mapping (string => address) Trojans;
mapping (string => string) secrets;
mapping (string => address[]) access;
mapping (string => uint) balance;
uint amount_for_unlock;

//constructor

constructor() public{
        name   = "Secrets"; 
        symbol = "S" ;
        amount_for_unlock = 1 ether;

}

function registerTrojan(string name) public returns(bool){
    if( Trojans[name] == address(0))  
    {
        memberCount ++;
        Trojans[name] = msg.sender;
        return True;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function unregisterTrojan(string name) public {
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    Trojans[name] = address(0);
    memberCount --;
}
function setSecret(string name,string message) public {
   require (Trojans[name] != address(0)&& Trojans[name] == msg.sender);
   secrets[name] = message;
}
function getSecret(string name) public view returns(string){
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    bool flag = false;

    for(uint i = 0; i < access[name].length;i++)
    {
        if(access[name][i] == msg.sender){
            flag = true;
            break;

        }
    }
     if(flag){
         return secrets[name];
     }
     return "message is locked";
}

}
function unlockMessage(string name) public payable returns (bool) {
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    if(msg.value == amount_for_unlock){

        balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;
        Trojans[name].transfer(msg.value);
        access[name].push(msg.sender);

        return true;
    } 
    else{
        return false;

    }    
}
```

}

Comment: seems like you have two closing curly brackets `}` for the `function getSecret` just before `function unlockMessage`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I have another compile error after clearing the extra curly braces. TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory.
            balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;

Comment: Just submitted a complete answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Several errors here:

i. double closing curly brackets for the function `getSecret` just before function `unlockMessage`

ii. Boolean identifier `True` rather than `true`

```
function registerTrojan(string name) public returns(bool){
    if( Trojans[name] == address(0))  
    {
        memberCount ++;
        Trojans[name] = msg.sender;
        return True; // <<<<< true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

iii. Type issue

- **balance** is map of type `String -> uint`. So when you call `Trojans[name]` it return an address.
- **Trojans** is map of type `String -> address`. When you call `balance[???]`, ??? is expected t be a String a per the definition of balance

Replace

```
balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;
```

By

```
balance[name] += msg.value;
```